# Significance Testing between marketing campaign variants with only constant spend

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, experiment-design

I'm testing two marketing campaigns against each other: the assets are exactly the same, but the main difference is the optimization event that I'm feeding the vendor (e.g. Snapchat/Facebook/etc.)

The one thing I'm holding constant is the spend amount (e.g. $1000/day) per campaign.

The vendor's optimization algorithms will potentially send more traffic to the higher performing campaign, so to evaluate the test I care about:

- Per variant, which one gives me the most signups per $
- Per variant, which one gives me the most purchases per $

What significance test should I use to determine a significant difference between the variants?

Comment: Are these two campaigns running at the same time and place? If so, there may be interference between the two groups that complicates the analysis.

Comment: If they're running on Facebook/Snapchat I would imagine this is a RCT. Each user is randomly assigned to one of the variants and so there should not be any interference between users.

Comment: I am worried that the test is set up as two campaigns bidding on the same set of users, which can drive up the price, violating SUTVA. Plus you have the ad platform dynamically adjusting the allocation between cells like a bandit.

Comment: @dimitriy I don't think that's the case but we'll let the OP share more details. The way I think it works is by randomly assigning users to a test branch and then only showing that variant. I don't see how randomly assigning one user to variant 1 would interfere with the propensity to react to the ad of a user in variant 2.

Comment: Hi! Yes there won't be any interference since this is using Snapchat and FB's RCT, ensuring that users won't see both variants - good question

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to run two separate and very similar tests.

The first one has signups per dollar (SPD) as its success metric. The hypotheses are:
$$
H_0: \operatorname{SPD}_1=\operatorname{SPD}_2 \\
H_1: \operatorname{SPD}_1\neq\operatorname{SPD}_2
$$
for variants $1$ and $2$.

The second test has purchases per dollar as its success metric. The test hypotheses are:
$$
H_0: \operatorname{PPD}_1=\operatorname{PPD}_2 \\
H_1: \operatorname{PPD}_1\neq\operatorname{PPD}_2
$$

You can test both sets of hypotheses with a t-test. Here's an example in R:

- First we simulate some data that might look like yours. Note that since the spend is held constant at \$1,000 every day you can simply use the daily signups/purchases (as dividing these by \$1,000 to get SPD/PPD won't change anything but the scale):

```r
set.seed(123)

test_data <- data.frame(
  days = rep(1:14, 2),
  variant = factor(rep(c(1,2), each = 14)),
  spend = rep(1000, 28),
  signups = c(rnorm(14, 500, 10), rnorm(14,520,10)),
  purchases = c(rnorm(14, 75, 5), rnorm(14,73,5))
)
```

- This is what the simulated data looks like:

```r
test_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = variant, y = signups)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(y = 'Signups per $1000 (SPD)')

test_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = variant, y = purchases)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(y = 'Purchases per $1000 (PPD)')
```

[image: SPD Boxplot]
[image: PPD Boxplot]

- Finally you can run the two t-tests like so:

```r
variant_1_spd <- test_data %>% 
  filter(variant == 1) %>% 
  select(signups) %>% 
  pull()

variant_2_spd <- test_data %>% 
  filter(variant == 2) %>% 
  select(signups) %>% 
  pull()

t.test(variant_1_spd, variant_2_spd, alternative = 'two.sided', var.equal = T)
```

*Output:*

```
    Two Sample t-test

data:  variant_1_spd and variant_2_spd
t = -4.1617, df = 26, p-value = 0.0003063
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -22.182470  -7.514668
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 502.0297  516.8783
```

and

```r
variant_1_ppd <- test_data %>% 
  filter(variant == 1) %>% 
  select(purchases) %>% 
  pull()

variant_2_ppd <- test_data %>% 
  filter(variant == 2) %>% 
  select(purchases) %>% 
  pull()

t.test(variant_1_ppd, variant_2_ppd, alternative = 'two.sided', var.equal = T)
```

*Output:*

```
    Two Sample t-test

data:  variant_1_ppd and variant_2_ppd
t = 0.94624, df = 26, p-value = 0.3527
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.832490  4.958795
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 75.86911  74.30595
```

Therefore, in this case we would reject the null hypothesis of equal SPD at the 1% level and conclude that variant $2$ gets us significantly more signups per $1,000. However, we could not reject the null hypothesis of equal PPD so we would conclude that there wasn't enough evidence that the different variants performed differently in terms of PPD.

As I said this is artificial data, but if you saw a similar conclusion then you should be concerned about the conversion rate of variant $2$, since it brings significantly more signups but these are less likely to convert (hence the lack of difference in PPD). Alternatively (or additionally), you could do a proportions test on the conversion rates of the two variants i.e. purchases / signups.

A final comment: note that in order to do this you must be happy with the assumption that the signups you get on one day are independent from the signups you get on another day (and the same applies to purchases). If you had reason to believe that the number of signups you got today were *not* independent from the signups you got yesterday, then that would violate a key assumption of a t-test. This could be the case if your marketing campaign had a cumulative effect over time, for example if the ads became more effective the longer they ran. If that was the case you might need to resort to other techniques (one that comes to mind is using [clustered standard errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustered_standard_errors)).

Comment: For picking the best marketing strategy, a one-sided test seems more appropriate than a two-sided one. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @dimitriy In the question the OP made it sound like there wasn't a control variant but two competing treatment variants. If there was a control, I'd probably agree. You could test $H_0: \operatorname{SPD}_c > \operatorname{SPD}_t$ vs. $H_1: \operatorname{SPD}_c \leq \operatorname{SPD}_t$. This way you'd conclude that your treatment variant was at least as good as control if you got a significant result (but you'd have more power because the rejection region would now be twice as large).

Comment: I am not sure if two treatments are fundamentally different than treatment and a control if the goal is to pick the best one. The control could just be the typical data feed.

Comment: OOoh thanks for the response. 

Re: "This could be the case if your marketing campaign had a cumulative effect over time, for example if the ads became more effective the longer they ran."


The campaigns definitely do become more effective over time - Thanks! I'll look into that